# What is the usual block cipher mode that goes with CTS

Tags: block-cipher, cbc, ecb

I am wondering: what is the most common, or most used, block cipher mode used that goes with CTS (CypherText Stealing)?

Is it [ebc](/questions/tagged/ebc) or [cbc](/questions/tagged/cbc)?

Comment: What is CTS?  CipherText Stealing?

Comment: Yes. I guess  this is really a matter of opinion.

Comment: You should not use ECB at all (it is insecure), so I hope it is not "usual".

Comment: What is the [tag:ebc] tag? I sense a typo from e-sushi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a NIST definition of CTS (CipherText Stealing) mode in [the addendum to NISTSP800-38A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/addendum-to-nist_sp800-38A.pdf).

The title of that addendum answers the question:

> "Recommendation for Block Cipher Modes of Operation: Three Variants of Ciphertext Stealing for CBC Mode".

The paper is also useful to understand that there are many different ways to do ciphertext stealing.